# ReflectionTestUtils.setfield is not overriding the local project property attribute

Tags: java, spring, microservices

I am struggling with how to override a property file inside a .yml file

We use the Spring framework and use annotations (eg. @InjectMocks).

I have a an attribute declared in a configuration project YML file called "one-platform-properties" called paysafe-ss-fx-service.yml.  It sets a variable called `maxRecoveryAge=0`.  It is essentially a time to live buffer.

```
  oneplatform:
  environment: local
publisher:
  rates:
    maxRecoveryAge: 0
    interPublishDelay: 500
```

The problem is that I want to be able to adjust this at run time in my tests.  Make the buffer to 1 hour, 5 hours and 24 hours.

I am using the `ReflectionTestUtils.setfield(PublisherClass, "maxDocumentAge", 1, int.class)` call in my tests to adjust the timing, but the value is not being overridden.  When I do a watch on the variable it is working in my test harness, but once the test run penetrates into the micro service code, the overridden value is lost.  Any ideas on how to have the overridden value persist throughout all the tests?

My goal is to use different variations on my test run:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(new FxRatesEventPublisher(),"maxRecoveryAge",1,int.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(new FxRatesEventPublisher(),"maxRecoveryAge",5,int.class);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(new FxRatesEventPublisher(),"maxRecoveryAge",24,int.class);
```

and essentially override the value as defined in the project defined properties file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(producerConfiguration, "messageProducer", realProducer);
Object target = AopTestUtils.getUltimateTargetObject(fxRatesEventPublisher);
int recoveryAge = -1;
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(target, "maxRecoveryAge", recoveryAge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [`@TestPropertySource#properties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__testpropertysource)?

> The following example demonstrates how to declare inlined properties.

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "timezone = GMT", "port: 4242" })
public class MyIntegrationTests {
    // class body...
}
```

Note that from that [javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestPropertySource.html):

> `@TestPropertySource` is a class-level annotation

This means that you'll need to have different classes for the different configuration values you want to use.

Comment: I tried this originally, but the values still did not get over-ridden.  See below for the ultimate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are not following the latest Spring conventions and best practices which tell us to [prefer constructor based injection over field based injection](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/).

If you had your bean declared like this:

```
public class FxRatesEventPublisher {
    private final Integer maxRecoveryAge;
    private final SomeDependency someDependency;

    public FxRatesEventPublisher(@Value("${publisher.rate.maxRecoveryAge}") Integer maxRecoveryAge, @Autowired SomeDependency someDependency) {
        this.maxRecoveryAge = maxRecoveryAge;
        this.someDependency = someDependency;
    }
}
```

then you could instantiate it like this:

```
// Create an instance with your test values injected. Note that you could inject mocked dependency here as well as the real one.
FxRatesEventPublisher fxRatesEventPublisher = new FxRatesEventPublisher(24, mockDependency);
```

In this case, it's much easier to test your components, as you can pass any values to the constructor. I agree that this seems to be less pretty than the property based injection, but worth taking a look at least.